# using bind in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Here is some of my code:

```
Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //This is our Task collection and holds our Task models
    initialize: function (models, options) {
        console.log(options);

      this.bind("add", options.view.addTaskListeners);
      console.log(this.bind("add", options.view.addTaskListeners));
      //Listen for new additions to the collection.
    }
  });


  AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("body"),
    initialize: function () {
      this.tasks = new Tasks( null, { view: this });
      // Create a task collection when the view is initialized.
      // Pass it a reference to this view to create a connection between the two

    },
    events: {
      "click #add-task":  "showPrompt",
    },

    showPrompt: function () {
        debugger;
      var task_name = prompt("What is your task");
      var task_time = prompt("How Long will it take");
      var task_model = new Task({ name: task_name, time: task_time });
      //Add a new task model to our friend collection
      this.tasks.add( task_model, task_time );
    },
    addTaskListeners: function (model) {
      //The parameter passed is a reference to the model that was added
      $("#task-list").append("<li>" + model.get('name') + "</li>");
      //Use .get to receive attributes of the model
    }
  });
```

In my View I have I have a showPrompt function that adds a model to the Collection.

```
this.tasks.add( task_model, task_time );
```

My collection has some form of an event listener, the code looks like this.

```
this.bind("add", options.view.addTaskListeners);
```

I believe these code snippets are speaking with each other. I believe the this.bind is listening for the add event.  I do not understand what the parameter 'options' is and why we have to call options.view.addTaskListeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the proper way to do it is not to pass the view object to the collection, but to add listeners like so:

```
  AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("body"),
    initialize: function () {
      this.collection = new Tasks();
      this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addTaskListeners);

    },
    events: {
      "click #add-task":  "showPrompt",
    },
....
```

This way when an `add` event is fired, it will run `addTAskListeners`.

So for adding new models to the collection, I would do it like so:

```
showPrompt: function () {
    debugger;
  var task_name = prompt("What is your task");
  var task_time = prompt("How Long will it take");
  this.collection.add({ name: task_name, time: task_time }) //you could use .create
  ...
},
```

You have access to the model from the collection, so you don't really need to instantiate the model on its own.